# Unable to add slack to bluemix project

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, slack

I've finally got the beta services added to my bluemix project.

But it's not very clear how the integration with slack should be configured.

I have an account, team, and channel already. The link in the instructions points to OAuth authentication. Your options are to register an app (but for that you need to know things like the secret, redirecting URI, etc). That can't be right...

Are there any more details available on how to configure Slack for a bluemix project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the linked documentation here: https://api.slack.com/web#authentication

There are 2 ways to authenticate with Slack. The first is to use a generated full-access token and the second is to register the application and use OAuth 2 with Slack.

Currently, the Bluemix project beta supports the first method of authentication only.  If you are logged into your Slack team(s) and go to the link above, you should see the option to generate tokens for each of the Slack teams you are a part of. That is the token you will need to enter when configuring the Slack integration on the integrations page for your Bluemix project. The other field that you must fill in is the Slack channel that you want to post events to, which you already seem to have.

Screenshot: 
[Screenshot indicating location of the token you must copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UEu9.png)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I actually tried that first, but perhaps it didn't work because there was leading spaces or something in the token. Anyway, would be useful to make the documentation more clear. Right now it contains a link to the OAuth page which talks more about registering an application with OAuth2